# ubuntu hotkey for window menu

Tags: hotkeys

How can i access to menu by keyboard, i mean the menu when you click on the left upper side on the window and see menu like this:

Maximazie
Minimaize
Move 
Resize

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: doesn't help to me

Comment: im sorry. Im using xfce WM, and shortkey will be A-F10
thanks